# How to escape invalid character like ... in routes?

Tags: javascript, escaping

There's a search bar in my webapp that can search people's name. I want to escape some invalid characters in the frontend to prevent undesired result, for example, searching `...` will lead to routing error. I tried to use javascript escape() function, but it can not escape `...` How should we deal with that?

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` is your friend. Also, you need to provide the html and javascript for us to see the problem.

Comment: This seems more like a problem with your routing function. Why is searching for `...` an error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `input.replace(/\W/g, '')`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/oqp8uoyf/